# Drag a file in to listbox

Tags: javascript

i develop a webpage , in that we allow user to drag a file into a list box or text box . after drag the file in to a listbox i need to read the file path of the file . Please help me to solve the issue .

Comment: Your question only raises more questions. What file are you talking about? Javascript has no access to files on client machine.

Comment: Not yet . i am googled it , But they guide to drag only , but i need to put it in a textbox and read it's name

Comment: Is this even possible? I thought it could only be done with a browser extension such as Gears...though happy to be proven wrong. Though even with that, chances are you can't get the file-path, only the file contents...

Comment: what the file may be , Ex:excel or word or GIF , When the user drag and drop it in textbox , i want to read the file name thats all

Comment: If I drop a file in a textbox, the path the file is the value of the textbox. After that you can read the path of it.

Comment: Ok friends , Thanks for sharing the information with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't drag and drop files onto a browser window like that.

Comment: "You can't drag and drop files onto a browser window like that" without HTML 5 or Google Gears

Comment: HTML5 will take years to be widely supported, and Gears is a plugin. Unless someone states that plugins / only specific browsers are OK, I tend to answer questions based on what's widely supported.